# Bash - Command call ported to variable with another variable inside

Tags: linux, bash

I believe this is a simple syntax issue on my part but I have been unable to find another example similar to what i'm trying to do. I have a variable taking in a specific disk location and I need to use that location in an hdparm /grep command to pull out the max LBA

```
targetDrive=$1   #/dev/sdb

maxLBA=$(hdparm -I /dev/sdb |grep LBA48 |grep -P -o '(?<=:\s)[^\s]*')  #this works perfect

maxLBA=$(hdparm -I $1 |grep LBA48 |grep -P -o '(?<=:\s)[^\s]*')  #this fails
```

I have also tried

```
maxLBA=$(hdparm -I 1 |grep LBA48 |grep -P -o '(?<=:\s)[^\s]*')
maxLBA=$(hdparm -I "$1" |grep LBA48 |grep -P -o '(?<=:\s)[^\s]*')
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The grep doesn't seem to work on my machine. I get no results running this directly with /dev/sda. You just need to get the sectors behind the LBA48 user addressable sectors: ?

Comment: Do you want the `**`s to be literal? They don't work for emphasis when used inside a code section.

Comment: Are you ENTIRELY certain that `$1` is, in fact, exactly what you expect it to be? I'd suggest running `printf 'First argument is: %q\n' "$1"`

Comment: This is what I came up so far ... sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep LBA48 | grep -P -o ".+LBA48.+:.+(\d+)" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' '

Comment: By the way, the version with `"$1"` quoted is the canonically correct form.

Comment: charles: Thank you for the heads up on the ** and my issue was I was still trying to use $1 even though I had already had a var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think here is the solution to your problem. I did basically the same as you but changed the way I pipe the results into one another.

- grep with regular expression to find the line containing LBA48
- cut to retrieve the second field when the resulting string is divided by the column ":"
- then trim all the leasding spaces from the result

Here is my resulting bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

target_drive=$1
max_lba=$(sudo hdparm -I "$target_drive" | grep -P -o ".+LBA48.+:.+(\d+)" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ')

echo "Drive: $target_drive MAX LBA48: $max_lba"
```

Comment: Well I didn't use all of your changes but you did make me realize my stupid error. I had target_drive already created yet I was still trying to use $1 in my command. changing $1 to $target_drive fixed everything

Comment: Oups, did'nt see that! Well I hope it helped you though!

Comment: @Trivial Unless your script has a `shift` in it or you were calling this code in a function, `$1` still should have worked, even after the assignment. (If you *did* have either of those things... well, you should have made your question include a complete enough reproducer for it to be clear).